# How to localise Facebook Objects and Actions

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

Apologies if this has already been asked or if this is a dumb question, but I can't seem to figure out how to localise OG actions and objects and the Facebook documentation has defeated me (again).

Scenario:

I have a single OG action called Like (the same action that FB creates automatically for apps that use the Like button).

I also have two objects: post and comment.

Stories are created by my app along the lines of "{name} likes a post on {app name}". In the activity panel they appear as "{name} likes {title} on {app name}". Note i *do not* have any OG Stories defined - I'm simply publishing the Like action along with one of the two objects I have created.

What I'm struggling to figure out is, how to localise the "likes a post on" and "likes" part of the stories being published to a user's timeline.

I am already generating the appropriate locale and locale:alternate OG meta tags that the FB scraper uses to build the stories. The two locales I support are en_GB and ar_AR and for the ar_AR locale I also include localised title and description meta tags.

When I publish a story for a test user with the AR locale selected, the story includes the localised title and description text in Arabic however the "likes a post on" and "likes" text is still in English. I've checked the localisation app in Facebook and there are no strings appearing to localise, whilst the localisation section within the app settings only provides areas for the app title and description and locale specific images.

Does anyone out there have any insight in to how I can localise the "likes a post on" and "likes" associated with the publishing of the Like action?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think you need to localise that text. Pretty sure Facebook translates this into the viewer's language. What is the language setting in Facebook for the user you are viewing the stories as? https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=account&section=language&view

Comment: @madebydavid thanks for the comment - I've made sure (and just confirmed) that the test users both have ar_AR set as the language. I thought the same as you but then I thought, what if I had of created an object called "spacefunk" - there's no way FB could auto translate that and yet I don't see how I can do it either. Very confusing and not the first time the documentation has beaten me!

Comment: Facebook translates the actions - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/internationalization/#actions but you may need to set your app up for translation. You can also restrict actions to certain geographic regions - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/creating-action-types/#advanced

Comment: @madebydavid If Facebook translates the action "like" in my case - and this is what I assumed in the first place - does it also translate my two custom actions "post" and "comment"? They're common words especially in the context of FB but all the evidence that I've seen so far suggests not. It _could_ be an issue specifically with test users, which wouldn't be the first time test users specifically have caused problems for me.